# Unit testing Spark transformation on DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Looking for suggestions on how to unit test a Spark transformation with ScalaTest.  The test class generates a DataFrame from static data and passes it to a transformation, then makes assertion on the passing static data generated in the test class.  (The transform creates a second column `b` defined as `col("a").plus(5)`.)

I got this to work but wonder if there's a better way to create the DataFrame?   `asJava` feels awkward, as does defining the row data and schema separately.

```
class TransformTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with SharedSparkContext {
  "Transformer" should "add column to dataframe" in {
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val rows = Seq[Row](
      Row(1),
      Row(2),
      Row(3)
     ).asJava
   val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("a", IntegerType)))

   val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
   val df2 = new Transform().addCol(df)
   assert(df2.count() > 0)
   assert(df2.agg(sum("a")).first.getLong(0) == 6)
   assert(df2.agg(sum("b")).first.getLong(0) == 21)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `asJava` looks awkward and completely unnecessary here. You can approach this problem in a few different ways.

- pass `RDD[Row]` instead of `Seq[Row]` to avoid `asJava`:

  ```
  sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(Seq(Row(1), Row(2), Row(3))), schema
  ```
- use product types instead of `Row` to avoid both `asJava` and passing schema:

  ```
  sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(1, 2,  3).map(Tuple1(_))).toDF("a")
  ```

  or

  ```
  case class Record(x: Int)

  sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(1, 2,  3).map(Record(_)))
  ```
- use implicit conversions to avoid `asJava` and passing schema and get concise syntax (supported for `Seq[Int]` only in Spark 2.0+):

  ```
  import spark.implicits._

  Seq(1, 2, 3).toDF("a")
  ```

In general you should prefer product types (tuples, case classes) over `Row` objects. You get schema for free as well as some static typing.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "product type"?

Comment: From theoretical perspective [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type), from practical subclasses of [scala.Product](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Product).